# Share data within the same template in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

Using the latest ionic 2 (Release) and Angular 2

[EDIT: Sorry, this question turned out to be too convoluted. I posted a more simplified version of this question at  [How to bind to an item in an ngFor loop in Ionic 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101970/how-to-bind-to-an-item-in-an-ngfor-loop-in-ionic-2) ]

In my application I am emulating a stack of cards 'tinder' style. I also have a Timer component that has a ‘timeInSeconds’ input. The Timer component displays a countdown on each card. The card and timer mechanisms are not really relevant to the question, but it's probably important to know that each card displays in turn (not like a scrolling list), and can be swiped away. Also, the Timer component just needs the one value (time in seconds) and will start counting down from that.

A very simplified version of the code is:

```
<ion-content>
    <div *ngFor="let c of cards">
        …
        <timer #timer [timeInSeconds]=“c.datetime”></timer>
        …
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

This will display each card in turn, including the timer. It works fine. However, I seem to lose a lot of cpu cycles by allocating a separate timer to each card - slowing down the app considerably (interestingly though, iOS seem to handle this much better than android).

Thus I want to have just the one timer display at the top of the page, which then changes each time I change card. Meaning something like this:

```
<ion-header>
    <timer #timer [timeInSeconds]=“_timespan”></timer>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    <div *ngFor="let c of cards" [timespan]=“c.datetime">
    …
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

In the ts, I try to read my own input:

```
public _timespan: number;
@Input()
    set timespan(value: number) {
        this._timespan = value;
    }
    get timespan() { 
        return this._timespan ; 
    }
```

But that doesn’t seem possible. I suspect I've totally lost the plot with my in- and outputs, as I'm quite new to angular. Can anyone put me on the right path please and suggest a way of accomplishing what I want?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you need setter and getter?

Comment: I did see it done like this in an article somewhere. What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: in your particular case having simple `public timespan: number;` is enough...

Comment: Thanks for your input sm... I realise now that my question is misleading and can be narrowed down significantly. So I posted a more simplified version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101970/how-to-bind-to-an-item-in-an-ngfor-loop-in-ionic-2. Could you have a look at this please?