# How to bind to an item in an ngFor loop in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

In my template, I have

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of items">
    <p>{{ item.timespan }}</p>
</ion-card>
```

However, instead of displaying the value inside the loop, I want to bind to it from somewhere else in the template, outside the ngFor loop, like

```
<h1>{{ timespan }}</h1>
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of items" [timespan]=“item.timespan”>
    …
</ion-card>
```

But I assume I can’t use [timespan] since it is not an input property of ion-card..

So does anyone know how else I can implement this binding?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried an `*ngFor` with `template`? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#star-template. It's also a little unclear just what you're trying to accomplish. Multiple elements rendered in the loop?

Comment: Thanks silentsod. I tried to simplify the code. In reality, the cards are wrapped into a 'swing-stack' from the Angular2-swing library. Instead of showing all the items in a list-like fashion, it shows each card in turn, to be swiped away in a tinder-like fashion. As regards using templates, that seems to be a good solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using `template` instead of `*ngFor` to handle the loop:

```
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items">
  <h1>{{item.timespan}}</h1>
  <ion-card>
  …
  </ion-card>
</template>
```

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0VzEHAIJl4AFxAPyApnK?p=preview) you can muck about with.

Comment: Thanks so much silentsod, this works. I do have added complications as all the timespans are showing at once, not one at a time. But that behaviour is to be expected given the situation I mentioned in the comments.